# Simple Caesar shift in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a simple [Caesar shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) program in C but I can't seem to figure it out. The program keeps crashing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int arc, const char* argv[])
{
    int shift = atoi(argv[1]);
    char message[256];
    strcpy(message, argv[2]);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(message); i++) {
        printf("%c", message[i] + shift);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you run something under Xcode it runs under the debugger.  LLDB is one of the debuggers that may be used.  Your output should appear in the debugger console.

Comment: Unless you are trying to force Xcode to do the encryption (which is highly unlikely, since it's not a data security tool but an IDE), this has precisely **nothing** to do with Xcode.

Comment: @H2CO3 - In this case I suspect it *does* have to do with Xcode, in the sense that he doesn't know how to use it.  For instance, to pass in parameters one must dink with the project settings (I forget the exact incantation).

Comment: Poopnugget, what is the exact symptom you're seeing?  What messages are displayed?

Comment: How large is your message?  Is it larger than, say, 256 characters?

Comment: @HotLicks you say something - still, he's supposed to learn using the compiler before relying on an IDE, and also the wording involving Xcode was not even near to sensible in the question - hence my edit.

Comment: By the way, how do you invoke the program? It's supposed to be called like this: `./progname shift 'the message'`.

Comment: @H2CO3 -- Before you put other words in his mouth, he said he *ran* the program with Xcode.  In order to pass in parameters he must know the proper Xcode incantation to set them.

Answer (score 5):

You're not correctly implementing the Caesar Cipher. Your code includes the following line, which is wrong:

```
printf("%c", message[i] + shift);
```

To do this correctly, you'll want to convert that to a function:

```
printf("%c", encrypt(message[i], shift));
```

And let's implement the function:

```
char encrypt(char input, int shift) {
    if (input >= 'a' && input <= 'z')
        return ((input - 'a' + shift) % 26) + 'a';
    if (input >= 'A' && input <= 'Z')
        return ((input - 'A' + shift) % 26) + 'A';
    return input;
}
```

And just to explain what the math is doing in that function:

1. `input - 'a'` tells us what position in the alphabet the input is (assuming input is a lowercase letter). So if the input is `'c'`, then we will get a `2` back. If the input is `'z'`, we get `25`.
2. `input - 'a' + shift` gets us the new position of the character that we are using to do the cipher. Note that this could be a larger number than the alphabet (26 characters).
3. So to solve that problem, we use modular arithmetic to bound that number between `[0 - 25]`.
4. Then adding 'a' to that character gets us the actual character we want to print.

Note that this only works because the character codes for `a` to `z` and `A` to `Z` are consecutive.

Comment: But that does not explain why the original program crashes.

Comment: @MartinR: That's fair. That being said, I'm not 100% sure that his crash is a SIGSEGV.

Answer (score 4):

There are three problems with your program.

1. The program reads from `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`, but it assumes that the program receives at least 2 arguments. If it doesn't receive this many, then it can crash or do arbitrary things. You should explicitly check that the program receives at least (or exactly) 2 command-line arguments:

   ```
   if (argc != 3) {
       fprintf(stdout, "Not enough arguments\n");
       exit(1);
   }
   ```

   Note: Rename `arc` to `argc`, and there is an extra implicit argument for the program   name, which is why we check for 3.)
2. The program copies `argv[2]` into a fixed-size buffer. If the message is longer than 255 characters (plus null terminator), then it can overwrite memory and cause arbitrary things to happen. In the current situation, you can process the characters of `argv[2]` directly without copying it to a temporary variable:

   ```
   for (i = 0; argv[2][i] != '\0' ; i++) {
       printf("%c", encrypt(argv[2][i], shift));
   }
   ```
3. The Caesar shift needs to wrap around after z or Z. See [sharth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18552672/839689).

Comment: Unrelated to this problem, but `putchar(...)` is shorter.

Comment: Sure, you're right. I decided to minimize changes to his code. Btw, thanks for fixing my formatting! I was really confused about how to do preformatted text within a list.

Comment: Yes of course. - (Code that is part of a list has to be indented by 8 spaces instead of 4.)